# putting a variable inside of quotes in python

Tags: python, string, variables, quotes

I have just started learning Python. I am trying to have the user input a number base, and a number, and convert that to decimal.

I've been trying to use the built in int function like this:

```
base = raw_input("what number base are you starting with?  \n")
num = raw_input("please enter your number:  ")
int(num,base)
```

My problem is that when you use that int function, the number your converting needs to be in quotes like so: `int('fff',16)`

How can I accomplish this when im using a variable?

Comment: You can convert a number to a string with `str(number)`, for example `str(10)` will return `'10'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quotes are not needed.  The quotes are not part of the string.

```
>>> int('fff',16)
4095
>>> da_number = 'fff'
>>> int(da_number, 16)
4095
```

You will, however, need to cast the base to an integer.

```
>>> base = '16'
>>> int(da_number, base) # wrong! base should be an int.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
>>> int(da_number, int(base)) # correct
4095
```

Answer (score 3):

The result of `raw_input()` will be a string, I think your issue is actually that `base` is still a string when you need it to be an integer.

Try the following:

```
base = raw_input('base? ')
num = raw_input('num? ')
print int(num, int(base))
```

For example:

```
>>> base = raw_input('base? ')
base? 16
>>> num = raw_input('num? ')
num? fff
>>> print int(num, int(base))
4095
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't quotes.  The problem is with data *types*.  `int` with a base expects an **integer base** and a **string number**.  So, in your case, you'd use:

```
int(num,int(base))
```

This takes the *strings* which are returned from `raw_input` and it constructs a suitable base from the `base` string while leaving `num` as a string as required by the `int` function.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes are there to tell Python that those characters should be interpreted as the contents of a String, not as language syntax.

When you have a variable, Python already knows that the contents are a string.  Not only do you not need the quotes, but adding them would confuse Python into thinking that you wanted a string holding the name of the variable.

So, both this:

```
int('fff',16)
```

and this:

```
someNumber = 'fff'
int(someNumber,16)
```

are doing the same thing as far as the `int()` function is concerned.

All that being said, `int()` can take a string or a number for the value, but must have a number for the base.  So, since `raw_input` always returns a string, you'd need to do something more like:

```
base = raw_input("what number base are you starting with?  \n")
num = raw_input("please enter your number:  ")
int(num,int(base))
```